# Is ${5^{2}}^{x}$ the same thing as ${25}^{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Today my teacher said that $5^{{(2)}^{(x)}}$ is the same thing as $5^{(2x)}$, i.e $25^x$
I couldn't understand it, and asked him how these two were equal. He explained it, I still couldn't understand (Maybe I'm just stupid!). What I don't understand is, $(5^2)^x$ can be equal to $25^x$ (one of the laws of exponents). But how come $5^{{(2)}^{(x)}}$ is the same thing as $25^x$?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ . Clear notation is essential to this question!

Comment: $5^{2^x}$ is $5$ raised to the power of $2^x$ while $(5^2)^x$ is $5^2$ raised to the power of $x$.

Comment: So, both are two different things, hence unequal? That's what you are saying?

Comment: $5^{(2^x)} \neq (5^2)^x$, in general. Exponent towers are evaluated top down by convention, so $5^{2^x} = 5^{(2^x)}$.

Comment: Plus in $x=3$, e.g.  Then $5^{2^3}=5^8$, but $5^{(2x)}=5^6$.

Comment: You know, you don't have to check with an authority to verify this is false.  Plug in some numbers and see for yourself.  Then ask the teacher about the mistake. (Probably they meant $(5^2)^x = 5^{2x}$.)

Answer (score 4):

We have $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, but $a^{(b^c)}$ is in general something completely different. For that reason (i.e., because the other convention could be written simpler), writing $a^{b^c}$ without parentheses is conventionally understood to mean $a^{(b^c)}$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the base of the exponent is positive, your teacher's assertion is correct.

$$(a^b)^c = a^{bc} = (a^c)^b, \quad a > 0$$

Edit: The post was changed and adding a few lines on the edited post.

$$a^{b^x} \neq a^{bx}$$

So your teacher's assertion is wrong.

Comment: My teacher actually said, ${5^{2}}^{x}=5^{2x}=25^x$

Comment: Oh I see. It wasn't clear from what you had written. Well in that case your teacher isn't right. Take for example $x = 3$. Then $5^{2^3} = 5^8$ and $5^{2\times 3} = 5^6$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Your teacher is wrong if he said that $5^{2^x}$ is the same as $5^{2x}=25^x$. The exponents of $5$ are not the same (in general) $2^x$ is not the same as $2x$

Comment: Yeah, should have been straight-forward for me. I actually got confused, I thought I probably was missing something. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check-

> Put $x=0$ in both the expressions.
>
> $$5^{2^0}=5^1=5$$
>
> but
>
> $$25^{0}=1$$

Clearly they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

What your teacher meant is that $(5^2)^x$ is the same as $25^x$ and $5^{2x}$. The convention used is that parenthesis has a higher priority than exponentiation. In general, we evaluate things inside the parenthesis first then apply any operator to it.

Comment: That's the problem. My teacher said, ${5^{2}}^{x}=5^{2x}=25^x$ Both are equal?

Comment: Your teacher might have made a mistake. $5^{2^x}$ is not the same as $5^{2x}$ since $2^x$ is not the same as $2x$ generally

Answer (score 0):

$(x^m)^n = x^{mn}$

So according to your problem ${(5^{2})^{x}}=5^{2x}=25^x$

Comment: $5^{2^x}$ is different from $(5^2)^x$ which is $5^{2x}$

Comment: Aren't those two, two different things? How is ${5^{2}}^{x}$ equal $5^{2x}$ ??

Comment: Opps. i missed a paranthesis